# Implementing selenium with Jenkins and PHPUnit

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, phpunit, jenkins

I'm trying to do set up some Selenium WebTests using PHPUnit, but php is no longer supported by Selenium IDE, does this mean I have to re-write all my tests into php in order to use this method?

I'm trying to set up a continuous integration system, but have never even used one before, I tried using jenkins-php.org but it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: *"but php is no longer supported by Selenium IDE"* ??? *"I tried using jenkins-php.org but it wasn't very helpful."* ???

Comment: Selenium IDE used to output PHP, newer versions have removed php and perl support. Jenkins-php is a tutorial site on setting up Jenkins for php, but the information is hard to understand/use. I had to do a lot of playing to get it to work.

Comment: Great to read you found an answer to your question. Please add it below so others can benefit of it. You can even select it later on as the answer (yes that works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer releasee Selenium IDE "claims" it does not support PHP,
But you can still convert your IDE to PHP or PHPUnit.

(In Selenium IDE) Option > Options > Enable Experimental Functions.
With this option checked you can switch your format under Options again.
You may still want to review your code.

Hope this helps and it is what you meant by "Selenium IDE does not support PHP".

Comment: Does not work anymore, still no PHP. There is a new Plugin tho which we can use.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/

It allows output from Selenium to PHP, either PHPUnit format or Selenium Testing.

However after all this playing around it became apparent that the best way was to use htmlSuite, it has the most support when it comes to automation and seems to work out of the box, whereas PHPUnit testing requires lots of tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hacking around it became apparent that the best solution is this tool:

http://www.enjoyxstudy.com/selenium/autoexec/index.en.html

It works out of the box, supports htmlSuite, works with windows and linux, runs most browsers, sends email reports, can get new tests from SVN, integrates with Jenkins well, and works with Selenium tests, its not PHP based tests but it works wonders compared to the other tools I tried out.

Really, so much easier, very user friendly, free and works out the box.